# How to allow space,comma,dot and alphabets in codeigniter validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

In my view page.I have a textbox for entering comments.In my codeigniter validation
that allow only alpha.

I need to allow space,comma,dot,hyphen in Comment field..
How this place in my validation set rules

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('e_comment', 'Comments', 'required|alpha');
```

Comment: how to set a callback function for allowing these things..?

Comment: use callback function, check input by regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do custom validation you will need to use a [callback](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) function.

```
// validation rule
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comments', 'required|callback_customAlpha');

// callback function
public function customAlpha($str) 
{
    if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z .,\-]+$/i',$str) )
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// custom error message
$this->form_validation->set_message('customAlpha', 'error message');
```

Comment: this works. BUT, it returns error message upon submission even if fields are blank and are not required. How?

Answer (score 0):

```
function alpha($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

In the rules, you can call it like follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comments', required|callback_alpha');
```

**EDIT 01**

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z_ .,\])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Change this

Comment: How can i prevent only | character ?

Comment: `return ( ! preg_match(|, $str))`

Answer (score 0):

Easy and Best way to do this ,

Go to `system/library/form_validation.`
and make a functions or extend the library:

```
public function myAlpha($string) 
    {
        if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z .,\-]+$/i',$string) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

now use it normally where you want it .

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comments', 'required|myAlpha');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment on another answer, I will add this improved answer of [jeemusu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171529/jeemusu) so as to include the issue raised by [jorz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6666668/jorz), which is to avoid raising the error message whenever the data entered is blank

```php
// validation rule
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comments', 'required|callback_customAlpha');

// callback function
public function customAlpha($str) 
{
    if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z .,\-]+$/i',$str)&& $str!= "" )
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// custom error message
$this->form_validation->set_message('customAlpha', 'error message');
```